# Allowing nginx to connect to a Unix domain socket with CentOS targeted SELinux policy

Tags: nginx, centos, selinux

I need to allow to connect to a Unix domain socket with CentOS targeted SELinux policy.

I came up with the following module:

```
module httpd_unix 0.0.0;

require {
        attribute file_type;
        class unix_stream_socket connectto;
        class sock_file write;
        type httpd_t;
}

type httpd_unix_t;
typeattribute httpd_unix_t file_type;
allow httpd_t httpd_unix_t: unix_stream_socket connectto;
allow httpd_t httpd_unix_t: sock_file write;
```

But the audit says:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1491380970.041:396): avc:  denied  { connectto } for  pid=985 comm="nginx" path="/run/tsubonesystem3/tsubonesystem3.sock" scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket
```

The context is set to the file, of course.

```
$ sudo ls -Z /var/run/tsubonesystem3/tsubonesystem3.sock
srw-rw----. tsubonesystem tsubonesystem system_u:object_r:httpd_unix_t:s0 /var/run/tsubonesystem3/tsubonesystem3.sock
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Solved: I had to fix the context of the socket bound to the Unix stream file. Its permission is inherited from the process creating it (the listener), so allow the connecting process to connect to the context of the listener.

For example, if your listener is running in `listner_t` and the connecting process is in `connector_t`:

```
allow connector_t listener_t: unix_stream_socket connectto;
```

In my case, the listener was running in `init_t`, but allowing nginx to listen any process in `init_t` was too much. I created a new context for the listener and allowed nginx to connect to the process using the context.

Answer (score -1):

After much searching the only operational solution I found was:

```
semanage permissive -a httpd_t
```

This was on a CentOS 7.4 virtual machine.

Comment: That effectively disables selinux for the httpd_t context. It's only supposed to be used to allow your webserver to run unimpeded long enough to fill the audit log with everything that would otherwise be denied, so you can make a policy to allow those actions, then make it enforcing again. It's not an "operational solution", it's a security hole.